# Rotating disk at the end of a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

[image]

[image]

I don’t understand the answer to part b. Why the disk won’t rotate about its center of mass if it is mounted to the rod by a frictionless bearing. Why can the disk be a mass point at the end of the pendulum?
Please don’t close the question, I’m not asking the answer. I want to know the difference between fixed and free situation. I don’t know what causes the disk rotate in the first situation when its fixed.

Comment: Why would it rotate at all given there is no friction? The disk retains its orientation as the rod pivots, because there is nothing to cause it to rotate. So, it cannot contribute to the total moment of inertia of the pendulum because it is not rotating (about the pivot point mentioned). As such, it is just an additional mass ("point like object") attached to the rod.

Comment: What’s the difference between fixed and free?  The disk doesn’t rotate in both situations. So why in the first situation it contributes to the total moment of inertia? And the friction force acts on the point the center of mass of disk contacts with the rod, there is no torque to cause it rotate about the center of its mass even though friction force exists.

Comment: _The disk doesn't rotate in both situations_ Yes, it does rotate in the first situation. Are thinking of rotation about the disk's COM? That is not what the author means. Also, why do you think there is a friction force in the first situation? The whole setup is rigid in the first part.

Comment: I don’t think there is friction force in both situations. But what makes the disk rotate in the situation? Or why can the disk rotate if it’s fixed in the first situation? And if it rotates in the first situation how it could be rigid, the distance between any particles and rod is changing as the did rotates about center of its mass. Thanks for reply.